# Pricing difference between GCP Marketplace and Compute Engine Pricing

Tags: google-cloud-platform

The pricing difference between deployment from the GCP marketplace and self-deployment on VM instances is very stark and also on across all the regions.

For example, to deploy a Gitlab CE instance by Bitnami from the marketplace vs installing Gitlab CE in an E2 Standard VM (4 Core, 16GB) instance, the estimated pricing difference is huge and that to also across all the regions.
I checked almost all the GCP pricing docs but couldn't find a reason for it. Can anyone provide some details on why there is such a stark difference in pricing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time the marketplace documentation are out of date. Ask the service support to have a refresh on the price. The Google Cloud cost doesn't change according to the app deployed on it; but you can have additional licence cost.

Comment: The pricing is shown when launching the instance, i.e, during instance configuration.